# using one dns (domain) for mutilple web applications

Tags: apache, dns, alias, mod-cluster

I have many jenkins instances each one is installed in a different server and using a different port to distinguish them (one for test, one for uat and the other for prd),
Is it possible to setup an alias (dns), and each time someone hit the url he add a context like /test, /uat or /prd to get the needed Jenkins? Do I need an apache httpd in this case? How can I use it if the answer is yes!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, apache httpd petty much helps here, and modify your httpd.conf something like below.

```
#With mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   "^/test/(.+)"  "http://new.example1.com:9808/docs/$1"  [R,L]

RewriteRule   "^/uat/(.+)"  "http://new.example2.com:8080/uat/$1"  [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, will test and let you know